bv space is a direct sum of $bv_0$ with a one dimensional subspace
We define
$bv=\{x=\{x_n\} | \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_{k+1} -x_k| < \infty , x_k \in \mathbb C\} $
$C_0=\{x=\{x_n\} | lim x_n = 0,x_k \in \mathbb C\} $
And
$bv_0=bv \cap c_0$
I need to prove that bv space is a direct sum of $bv_0$ with a one dimensional  subspace.
I tried to find this one dimensional subspace but I only Know $\mathbb C $ and $\mathbb R$ as a one dimensional spaces. but I can't use any of them because I need a space of sequences that I don't have any idea about it.
Any help?

We have to understand how the sequences in $bv$ behave. Note that by the triangle inequality, for $k, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(x_n) \in bv$:
\begin{align}
\lvert x_{k+n} - x_n \rvert \leq \sum_{\ell = n}^{k-1} \lvert x_{\ell+1}-x_\ell\rvert
\end{align}
As $\sum_{\ell =1}^\infty \lvert x_{\ell+1} - x_\ell \rvert < \infty$, the above converges to $0$ as $k, n \rightarrow \infty$, which means that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy-sequence. By completeness of $\mathbb{C}$, the sequence $(x_n)$ has a limit $\ell^*$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
So we can write:
$$
x_n = \underbrace{\big(x_n - \ell^*)}_{\in c_0} + \underbrace{\ell^*}_{\in \mathrm{span}((1, 1, 1, ...))}
$$
So the one dimensional subspace (here, it is a subspace of the space of sequences) you are looking for $\mathrm{span}((1, 1, 1, ...))$.

Thank you very much

You know lots and lots and lots of one-dimensional spaces. Take any nonzero vector $v$ on any complex-vector space, and then $\mathbb Cv=\{\lambda v:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\}$ is a one-dimensional subspace. And of course the same idea works with any vector space over any field.
Now, as for your problem, if $x\in bv$ then $x$ is convergent. Indeed, such $x$ is Cauchy; for given $\def\e{\varepsilon}\e>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that $\sum_{n>n_0}|x_{k+1}-x_k|<\e$, and then for any $m>n>n_0$,
$$
|x_m-x_n|\leq\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}|x_{k+1}-x_k|<\e. 
$$
Let $c=\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k$. If $z$ is the constant sequence $\{1\}$, then $x-cz\in c_0$. So $x=(x-cz)+cz$, where $x-cz\in bv_0$ and $cz\in \mathbb Cz$.

Thank you very much
